# efficient way of getting chars out of zip file

Tags: c++, xml, boost, boost-iostreams

I am using a function which needs content from zipped xml file. The signature of the function is

```
endgoalFn(const char* s, int len)
```

Below is the code i use for unzipping

```
std::ifstream file;
file.open(resultFile, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> in;
in.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
in.push(file);
```

Below code i use for copying the content to a string and provide it to endgoal fn

```
std::stringstream buffer;
boost::iostreams::copy(in, buffer);
std::string content(std::move(buffer.str()));


endgoalFn(&content[0], content.size());
```

The three lines before calling endgoalFn takes x amount of ms depending on the size of the zipped file.

Is there any alternate way i can get the input for first argument in endgoalFn from filtering_streambuf so that i can decrease x amount of ms by few ms?

**Update**

it was suggested in comments to measure using optimized build.

[example code contains two ways (original and the one suggested by @sehe)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98131edd956aba29)

```
2.4M    resultFile
Consuming 7975424 bytes
withSStream, time taken: 136ms
Consuming 7975424 bytes
withoutSStream, time taken: 160ms
```

Comment: Are you using an optimised bulid? How big is the zip file? How long does it take to load?

Comment: The boost libraries are often quite slow if to run as not optimized debug builds (that people often do when they develop software). Are you measuring performance of such debug build?

Comment: zipped file size is 153342 bytes.

std::stringstream buffer;
boost::iostreams::copy(in, buffer);
std::string content(std::move(buffer.str()));

these 3 lines take 641 ms.

this is for my own project use. I am okay with the x amount of seconds but i was thinking if it is possible to decrease it anyway / if there's any alternate way of getting the first argument to endgoalFn than the way i did it which can probably take lesser time.

Comment: 641 ms is not "x amount of seconds" but "half a second or so". Also you consistently fail to answer if you are using optimised build or not.

Comment: sorry it took me a bit of time to understand what is meant by optimized build and debug build. I am using visual studio for running my code and "Optimization" is "Disabled". The configuration manager has Debug as "Configuration" under Project contexts. So i guess its debug build.

also, i have edited my question block to have correct time unit.

Comment: Don't benchmark performance of debug builds. They are slow. Test optimized/release builds.

Comment: Switch the Debug to Release in the combo box on the toolbar and retest. I have had cases where a debug mode took 100 times as long to run as release with the same data and code.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, make sure you measure in Release build configuration.

Besides, there is no need to move to a string stream first:

```
std::ifstream file;
file.open(resultFile, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> in;
in.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
in.push(file);
```

Now you can directly

```
std::string content(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in), {});
endgoalFn(content.data(), content.size());
```

### More Ideas

If XML files can be large, and **if** `endgoalFn` can handle partial input (e.g. you can call it in a loop) you can do a buffered read:

```
char buf[4096];
while (in.read(buf, sizeof(buf)) || in.gcount()) {
    endgoalFn(buf, in.gcount());
}
```

### UPDATE - Live Demo

See both demonstrated with a slightly modified sample that is self-contained:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55a090b625173999)**

```
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

namespace bio = boost::iostreams;

void endgoalFn(char const*, size_t n) {
    std::cout << "Consuming " << n << " bytes\n";
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open("resultFile", std::ios::binary);

    bio::filtering_stream<bio::input> in;
    in.push(bio::gzip_decompressor());
    in.push(file);

#ifndef STREAMING
    std::string const content(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in), {});
    endgoalFn(content.data(), content.size());
#else 
    char buf[4096];
    while (in.read(buf, sizeof(buf)) || in.gcount()) {
        endgoalFn(buf, in.gcount());
    }
#endif
}
```

Compiled for STREAMING:

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -DSTREAMING -lboost_iostreams -lz
cat a.out | gzip > resultFile
./a.out
```

Prints e.g.

```
Consuming 4096 bytes
Consuming 4096 bytes
// ...
Consuming 4096 bytes
Consuming 2856 bytes
```

Comment: i tried your first solution.
At compilation i got error
error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input,char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>,boost::iostreams::public_>' to 'std::istreambuf_iterator<char,std::char_traits<char>>'

then i changed the error line to  
std::string content(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(&in), {}); 
This compiled but the time for just std::string content(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(&in), {}); line went to 7890 ms from 641 ms. Am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Did you switch to Release build? (And yeah, I missed the fact that your filter chain was a streambuf, not a stream; one reason to make your question self-contained, so people can easily compile it - and their suggestions).

Comment: Added a live demo that illustrates both my approaches: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55a090b625173999

Comment: I took your live demo example as base. The results : [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98131edd956aba29) show stringstream taking lesser time. Now i am a bit confused with why it is so. Am i still doing something wrong ?
`2.4M resultFile
Consuming 7975424 bytes
withSStream, time taken: 136ms
Consuming 7975424 bytes
withoutSStream, time taken: 160ms`
sorry my prev test results were not with release build. I will keep your and other's suggestions in mind next time i put question.

Comment: Additionally, i like the "More Ideas" approach but the original "endgoalFn" i have does not support partial inputs.